# Live Tile Notification Not Showing

Tags: gml, game-maker

Hi I've been working at this for a while without success. I'm trying to send a simple notification to the live tile for my Native Windows 8 game. To get used to it I tried to use the example mentioned in the docs:

```
var expiryTime;
expiryTime = date_current_datetime();
expiryTime = date_inc_minute(expiryTime, 5);
win8_livetile_notification_begin("TileSquarePeekImageAndText01");
win8_livetile_notification_expiry(expiryTime);
win8_livetile_notification_tag("tag0");
win8_livetile_notification_text_add("Current Score = " + score);
win8_livetile_notification_image_add("ms-appx:///" + working_directory + "ScoreTile.png");
win8_livetile_notification_end();
```

Now this code crashes my app. Can someone tell me how to post a tile notification and where we should put the images. Right now I have the images inside of the Included Files folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

score is a real value, not a string, so you must write:

```
win8_livetile_notification_text_add("Current Score = " + string(score));
```

There's no typecasting in GameMaker and never was.